# how can I calculate dfs used in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a simple question.
dfs used in my hadoop UI is about 3TB but I have 1.4TB data in my hdfs.
dfs used is data usage*3 because of replication 3?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

DFS usage on Namenode UI = Total space used on cluster on all the datanodes.

If the replication factor is 2, it will be "data on one datanode * 2"

You can check overall and individual usage of DFS on the cluster using the below command -

`hdfs dfsadmin -report`